# And and Or logic reversed in basic while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop, boolean-logic

I've just started use rails but this logic seems reversed to me.

```
weight = 70
num_pallets = 25
while weight < 100 and num_pallets <=30
    weight += 1
    num_pallets += 1
    puts weight
end
```

I feel since the loop is supposed to run while both criteria are met the output should run up to 100 for weight.
HOWEVER...

```
When I use and the output is 70 71 72 73 74 75, 76
when I use "or" in place of "and" the output is 70, 71 ... 100
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails.  This is ruby code.

Comment: Sorry, all. I'm learning about the community, tags and how to accept answers. Totally working on changing by foolish ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while weight < 100 and num_pallets <=30
```

will run until either `weight >= 100` or `num_pallets > 30` because that will make the statement false

```
while weight < 100 or num_pallets <=30
```

will run until both `weight >= 100` and `num_pallets > 30` are true as that will make the statement false.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to analyzing this.

```
while weight < 100 and num_pallets <=30
    weight += 1
    num_pallets += 1
    puts weight
end
```

At the end the opposite will be true.

```
weight >= 100 or num_pallets > 30
```

Many folks do this kind of logic in reverse.

1. Write down what should be true at the end of the loop.
2. Write down the logical inverse of that condition.
3. Use the inverse condition for the `while`.

There's more to it than this, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

`and` returns true if both of the operands are true.

In your case, `num_pallets` is `31` after 6 iterations, resulting in a false second expression, thus the whole expression returns `false`.

`or` returns true if either of the operands is true. In the first 6 iterations, both expressions are true (`weight` is below 100 and num_pallets is below or equal 30). In the seventh iteration, `num_pallets` is 31, thus the second expression is false, but `weight` is still below 100, so the loop runs until `weight` is larger than 100.

Answer (score 0):

the loop is supposed to run while both criteria are met - correct.

SO, if one of the criteria fails the loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

As written, this loop will only execute 5 times because your `while` statement currently requires **BOTH** statements to be true. Consequently, because `num_pallets` begins at 25 and ends at 30, this loop will only execute 5 times. However, if you change the line to read:

```
weight, num_pallets = 70, 25
while weight < 100 || num_pallets <=30    #Changed to "OR"
  weight, num_pallets = weight + 1, num_pallets + 1
  puts weight
end
```

... it will run 30 times. Note that the only meaningful change above is the change from AND to OR in the `while` line.